# Why does SQLite say that instr doesnt exist?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to run a query:

```
SELECT name
FROM Foo 
WHERE instr(name, '@') = 0 AND instr(name, '.') != 0
```

But I am getting the error: "no such function: instr". This confuses me because [the website clearly states](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) that the function exists. Anyone know what is going on?

P.S. I also tried the query in SQLiteSpy which gives the same error.

Comment: This was [added in 3.7.15](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) (released in December) - What version are you running?

Comment: @MikeChristensen ah ha! I am using 3.7.14.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [Change History](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html), the `instr` function was added in version 3.7.15:

> **2012-12-12 (3.7.15)**
>
> Added the instr() SQL function.

Make sure you're running the latest release.

If upgrading is not an option, you can also use the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT name
FROM Foo 
WHERE name NOT LIKE '%@%' -- name does NOT contain @
AND name LIKE '%.%';      -- name DOES contain .
```

Comment: instr(x,y) returns the position in x of the string of y. LIKE returns true or false. Not even remotely equivalent for all uses.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply they're equivalent, just that it's a work around for the use case described in the original post.