# SQLite version on an AVD

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade, android-virtual-device

I need to use the INSTR function in SQLite3. Searching on SO indicates that the function is implemented in 3.7.15 and above. My AVD's SQLite version is 3.7.11, 
`SQLite version 3.7.11 2012-03-20 11:35:50` (as determined from the ADB shell when the AVD is running). So the function obviously fails with the runtime error `INSTR: No such function.`

My question is, how do I **upgrade the SQLite version on an AVD**?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887558/why-does-sqlite-say-that-instr-doesnt-exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887558/why-does-sqlite-say-that-instr-doesnt-exist)

Comment: Beg to differ, M D, the answers suggest workarounds. My question is plain and simple, **how to upgrade the SQLite version on an AVD**.

Comment: Still a duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/26087182/1321873

Comment: Agreed, M D and Rajesh. Thanks!